# Why can we assign FutureTask<V> object to Future<V> variable?

Tags: java, concurrency, future, futuretask

Here is the snippet from the book *Java Concurrency in Practice* that confused me:

```
interface Computable<A, V> {
    V compute(A arg) throws InterruptedException;
}

public class Memoizer3<A, V> implements Computable<A, V> {
        private final Map<A, Future<V>> cache
                 = new ConcurrentHashMap<A, Future<V>>();
        private final Computable<A, V> c;

        public Memoizer3(Computable<A, V> c) { this.c = c; }

        public V compute(final A arg) throws InterruptedException {
            Future<V> f = cache.get(arg);
            if(f == null) {
                Callable<V> eval = new Callable<V>() {
                    @Override
                    public V call() throws Exception {
                        return c.compute(arg);
                    }
                };
                FutureTask<V> ft = new FutureTask<V>(eval);

                //How could it happen???
                f = ft;

                cache.put(arg, ft);
                ft.run();
            }
            try {
                return f.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw launderThrowable(e.getCause());
            }
        }
    }
```

As the code shows, the type of *f* is Future while the *ft*'s type is FutureTask. Why could we assign *ft* to the variable *f*?

Comment: FutureTask is base concrete implementation of Future interface and provides asynchronous processing.

Answer (score 2):

`Future<V>` is an interface implemented by `FutureTask<V>`, so there is nothing wrong in doing that. If a class `C` implements an interface `I`, you can assign that class to a variable having type `C` as well as to one having type `I`. Be aware that in the second you will be able to interact only with the subset of methods exposed by `I`, instead of the whole set offered by `C`.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) the documentation of `FutureTask`.